# Python Selenium: get_elements method does not get li items in ul

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to get li items in a ul. Here is my code:

```
driver.get('https://migroskurumsal.com/magazalarimiz/')

try:
    select = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'stores'))
    )
    print('Dropdown is ready!')
except TimeoutException:
    print('Took too much time!')

select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID,'stores'))

select.select_by_value('2')

try:
    shopList = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "shopList"))
    )
    print('Shoplist is ready!')
except TimeoutException:
    print('Took too much time!')
    driver.quit()


print(shopList.get_attribute("class"))


li_items = shopList.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'li')

print(len(li_items))
```

I located the ul element with id=shopList successfully. Then I tried to get all of the li elements under ul by using find_elements(By.TAG_NAME). I also tried find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME), however the len(li_items) is always 0. I kindly request your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case waiting until `EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "shopList"))` does not do the trick, as this `ul` is already on the page, even before selecting filters, it's just empty. Instead, you could wait until `li` child elements are visible.

Example:

```
driver.get('https://migroskurumsal.com/magazalarimiz/')

try:
    select = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'stores'))
    )
    print('Dropdown is ready!')
except TimeoutException:
    print('Took too much time!')

select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'stores'))

select.select_by_value('2')
shopList = driver.find_element(By.ID, "shopList")
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='shopList']/li"))
    )
    print('Shoplist is ready!')
except TimeoutException:
    print('Took too much time!')
    driver.quit()

print(shopList.get_attribute("class"))

li_items = shopList.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')

print(len(li_items))
```

Results with output:

```
Dropdown is ready!
Shoplist is ready!
shop-list list-unstyled
601
```